# How can the roll over effect of one image again and again can be achieved in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

We need to create a screensaver where image should roll over again and again continuously to the left. We coded as shown below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
    .animator {
      background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Jordansallotments.jpg);
      animation: move-background 2s linear infinite;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    @keyframes move-background {
      0% {
        background-position: 0%, 0%;
      }
      100% {
        background-position: 100%, 0%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="animator"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The image is rolling over again and again as expected but every 2seconds, we are getting flickering effect. Please see the demo here.

[As a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3wkfb65/)

Can any one please help me to fix this or is there any way to achieve the effect of rolling one image over and over continuously using javascript?

I tried with javascript as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bdg_img = document.getElementById('bdgimg');
    var animate;
    function moveRight()
    {
        bdg_img.style.left = bdg_img.style.left || 0;
        bdg_img.style.left = parseInt(bdg_img.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
        animate = setTimeout(moveRight,40); // call moveRight in 20msec
    }
    moveRight();
</script>
```

But this is only moving the image to right. The image is not rolling over.

Comment: what you want if image is smaller than the container?

Comment: @appleapple: I didn't understand your question. How that is related.

Comment: it's related, I would guess you want repeat. do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percentage value in `background-position: xxx%` is relative  to the element's size, not to your actual image's.

So if you want to keep the original `background-image-size`, you will have to set this `background-position` relative to your media's size:

```css
.animator {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Jordansallotments.jpg);
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  animation: move-background 2s linear infinite;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

@keyframes move-background {
  to {
    /* the image is 1225*800px */
    background-position: -1225px 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animator"></div>
```

Also note that when you do

```
background-position: 100%, 0%;
```

You are actually setting two *background-position* rules, which would be used only if you did set two background-image rules, and is indeed a short-hand for :

```
background-position-x: 100%, 0%;
background-position-y: 100%, 0%;
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @Kaiido for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use very long animation time and repeat background to produce the effect.

*this animation play more than 10day (and may flicker once), but you can make it longer if you want.

*of course you can do the same thing (modify the style) in `javascript` by `setInterval` or alike. and have real infinity duration (at least until it reach numeric limit).

```css
.canvas{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Jordansallotments.jpg);
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  
  animation: move-background 1000000s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move-background {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -20000000px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas"></div>
```